# Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin. :processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

Tags: android, ionic-framework, geolocation, cordova-plugin-fcm

Hi in my Cordova project(Ionic v1) I'm using a background-location plugin for location tracking. The plugin working fine when I run alone but I also need the Cordova plugin cordova-plugin-fcm for GCM. Now when I run my project I'm getting this error.

[image: Following is the log after running ionic cordova run android command]

Installed plugins

```js
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-actionsheet" spec="2.3.3" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="2.4.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="1.1.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.3" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-fcm" spec="^2.1.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated" spec="^2.2.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="4.3.3" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="1.6.3" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" spec="1.0.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" spec="2.2.5" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="2.4.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.2.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.1.3" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="5.1.8" />
  <plugin name="es6-promise-plugin" spec="4.1.0" />
  <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the mauron85-background-geolocation. It sets the com.google.android.gms package to a version that is incompatible with google-services plugin.
I could build my app successfully by changing the platforms/android/build.gradle line

> compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"

to

> compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1"

after that I run my app directly in android studio because the cordova run command overwrite this change.

I will try to find a way to fix it directly via cordova and edit this answer.

Comment: As you said, after replacing '+' with version, and building project again with 'cordova build android', it overwrites gradle file. Without rebuilding it and running it directly on studio gives me same error on studio console.
Is there any way to rebuild it again without overwriting build file? I need built apk file for testing purpose and build fails due to above mentioned  version conflict.